# WPF DataGrid Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm using the WPF toolkit datagrid and in the past have always created entities for the grid to bind to, so for example a Contact Entity with Name, Address etc. 
On the current app I'm working on the user may select from 50 tables and individually select the fields from the tables to generate a view. 
Clearly here having an Entity to bind to will not work as the binding source will be dynamic.

Question is what do I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just [blogged](http://www.paulstovell.com/dynamic-datagrid) about how to dynamically create columns for a DataGrid based on a reusable model.

Comment: Paul, the code in your blog worked! One issue I am facing is that at the end there is one more column added which has the title "Properties" and all the column values are "(Collection)" without the quotes. kindly let me know why that column coming up. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use `Anonymous Types` it works perfectly, see the following proof of concept:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="136" Width="525"
    Loaded="OnWindowLoaded">
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">

</DataGrid>
```

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace MyProject {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Job { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Employee> _empCollection;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Generate test data
            _empCollection =
                new ObservableCollection<Employee>
                    {
                        new Employee {Id = 234, Code = "E041", Name = "Employee1", Job = 1, Address = "..."},
                        new Employee {Id = 245, Code = "E701", Name = "Employee2", Job = 3, Address = "..."},
                        new Employee {Id = 728, Code = "E001", Name = "Employee3", Job = 9, Address = "..."},
                        new Employee {Id = 663, Code = "E051", Name = "Employee4", Job = 7, Address = "..."},
                    };

            DataContext =
                (from i in _empCollection
                select new {i.Code, i.Name, i.Address}).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to create a collection of objects, and give each object a custom [TypeDescriptor](http://www.paulstovell.com/editable-object-adapter).

When the grid is auto generating columns, it uses reflection over your class - e.g., Customer, and discovers its properties - e.g., FirstName, Balance, etc.

But that's not entirely true. WPF doesn't do the work itself - it asks a TypeDescriptor. And you can implement your own TypeDescriptor, so you can **pretend to have properties that don't actually exist**. Or in your case, pretend *not* to have properties that do exist.

Comment: +1 for the great great link. i'd give +2 if there was an option :)

Answer (score 0):

You can leave binding source as it is, however you can filter DataGrid's columns based on user's preferences of what he/she needs to hide or see.